# Primitive Pythagorean triple generator

Tags: geometry, number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I was wondering how to prove the following fact about primitive Pythagorean triples:

> Let $(z,u,w)$ be a primitive Pythagorean triple. Then there exist relatively prime positive integers $a,b$ of different parity such that $$z = a^2-b^2, \quad u = 2ab, \quad \text{and} \quad w = a^2+b^2.$$

I see how $z,u,w$ must form the sides of a triangle, where $c$ is the hypotenuse, but how do we show that $\gcd(z,u,w) = 1$ and that these generate all the triples?

Comment: See proof in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy to see that if $(z,u,w)$ is a primitive pythagorean triple, then $w$ is odd and either $z$ is odd and $u$ is even or $z$ is even and $u$ is odd. WLOG suppose that $u=2x$ is even, so $z$ is odd. Then

$$u^2=4x^2=w^2-z^2=(w+z)(w-z).$$

It is plain that $\gcd(w+z,w-z)=2$, so $y_1:=(w+z)/2$ and $y_2:=(w-z)/2$ are relatively prime positive integers. Thus

$$x^2=y_1y_2,$$

and therefore $y_1$ and $y_2$ are relatively prime divisors of $x^2$. This implies that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are perfect squares, so write $y_1=a^2$ and $y_2=b^2$. Hence,

$$u=2x=2ab,\quad z=y_1-y_2=a^2-b^2,\qquad\text{and}\qquad w=y_1+y_2=a^2+b^2.$$

This proves that every primitive triple has the form $(a^2-b^2,2ab,a^2+b^2)$, as wanted.

Of course, the condition $\gcd(a,b)=1$ is needed, otherwise $(a^2-b^2,2ab,a^2+b^2)$ won't be primitive.

Comment: Why must $w$ be odd?

Comment: Suppose the $w$ is even. Then $z$ and $u$ have the same parity. If both are even, then the triple is not primitive. If both are odd, then $w^2$ is multiple of $4$, but $z^2+u^2$ is not multiple of $4$ (it is $\equiv2\bmod 4$ since $x^2\equiv1\pmod4$ for any odd $x$), which is a contradiction. Therefore, $w$ must be odd.

Comment: Even with A odd, B even, C odd, in a triple, it may not be primitive as in $(27,36,45), (75,100,125), (147,196,245), (243,324,405)$ with $GCDs$ of $3^2, 5^2, 7^2, 9^2$, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Even in the *wikipedia* article cited by @JeanMarie I could not find the following quick argument which gives all the Pyhagorean triples at one stroke: the Pythagorean equation being homogeneous, it is equivalent to the equation in rational variables $Z^2 + U^2 = 1$, or equivalently $N(Z + iU) = 1$, where $N$ denotes the norm map from $\mathbf Q(i)$ to $\mathbf Q$ , $i^2 = - 1$. The extension $\mathbf Q(i)/\mathbf Q$ being cyclic, with Galois group generated by the complex conjugation, Hilbert's theorem 90 applies, which shows that $N(Z + iU) = 1$ iff $Z + iU$ is of the form $A + iB /A - iB$. It follows from identification that $Z = A^2 - B^2 /A^2 + B^2$ and $U = 2AB / A^2 + B^2$. Clearing denominators immediately produces the usual Pythagorean integral triples $z = a^2 - b^2 , u = 2ab, w= a^2 + b^2$. Clearing common factors plainly gives the primitive triples.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had a proof that, if $m,n$ are mutually prime, $m,n$ would generate only primitive Pythagorean triples. The $proof$ is between the asterisk below.
$$\text{*************************}$$

$\text{We are given }\quad A=m^2n^2\quad B=2mn\quad C=m^2+n^2$

Let $x$ be the GCD of $m,n$ and let $p$ and $q$ be the cofactors of $m$ and $n$ respectively. Then we have

$$A=(xp)^2-(xq)^2\quad B=2xpxq\quad C=(xp)^2+(xq)^2$$
$$A=x^2(p^2-q^2)\quad B=2x^2(pq)\quad C=x^2(p^2+q^2)$$

If $GCD(m,n)=1$, then $GCD(A,B,C)=1$ and $(A,B,C)$ is a primitive triple. This means that $m$ and $n$ must be co-prime to generate a primitive.

$$\text{*************************}$$

However, a counter-example destroys to so-called proof: $\quad\text{Let }m,n=7,3$.
$$A=49-9=40\quad B=2*7*3=42\quad C=49+9=58\quad GCD(40,42,58)=2$$
 $$\therefore GCD(m,n)=1\neg\implies GCD(A,B,C)=1$$
The only two formulas I know about that will generate only primitive triplets do not generate all of them but $C-B=1$ in the first one and $C-A=2$ in the second one.

$$A=2n^2+1\quad B=2n^2+2n\quad C=2n^2+2n+1$$
$$A=4n^2-1\quad B=4n\quad C=4n^2+1$$

Comment: Where can I find more information about Ellingson'sequation? Wikipedia does not give any.

Comment: Can we have a chat on this channel (I don't want to compromise the integrity of an unpublished paper)? Because i know of a similar equation first given in 628 CE (about 1500 years ago). So I think it is not very new (I may be wrong, so in that case I apologize)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94402/discussion-between-rtn-and-poetasis).

Comment: So you have thought up some equations, have not published them and yet decided to just name them ellingson equations, probably using your own name? That is not good scientific practice.

Comment: I don't understand why there's an argument.  You give various formulas which are the well-known formula of Pythagoras. $$x^2+y^2=z^2$$ $$x=2ps$$ $$y=p^2-s^2$$ $$z=p^2+s^2$$ Your whole game... this is a substitution of numbers of another form. Like this. $$p=2n-1+k$$ $$s=k$$  It's not worth the time. Another formula describing all the solutions - can not be obtained...

Comment: Euclid's formula generates trivial triples e.g. $f(1,1)=(0,2,2), 2^{nd}$ quadrant triples e.g. $f(2,3)=-5,12,13)$, and non-odd multiples of triples e.g. $f(3,1)=(8,6,10)$. The alternative equations generate only non-trivial $1^{st}$ quadrant triples where $GCD(A,B,C)=(2m-1).m\in \mathbb{N}$ for all natural number pairs. The alternative generates all primitives  and that's all that are really needed.